# Parent an object to a face tracker with a delay in Spark AR Studio?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Hi I'm an animator new to coding I was wondering if it was possible to parent an object to the face tracker but with a short delay of 200 milliseconds or so, I have tried in the patches editor and with a script but have hit brick walls both times. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the expSmooth() method:
https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/reactivemodule

For example:

```
let dampening = 1000;
myObject.transform = face.cameraTransform.expSmooth(dampening);
```